# What is the best practice to use when using PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, html, formatting

I have been designing websites for a while now, but there is one thing that I have never been quite sure of when using PHP and HTML. Is it better to have the whole document in PHP and `echo` HTML like so:

```
<?php
  doSomething();
  echo "<div id=\"some_div\">Content</div>";
?>
```

Or have a HTML file like so and just add in the PHP:

```
<html>
<body>
  <?php doSomething(); ?>
  <div id="some_div">Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems tidier to `echo` HTML, especially if lots of PHP gets used throughout the page, but doing so loses all formatting of the HTML i.e. colors in the IDE etc.

Comment: I am not a crack in PHP but the best way is that you have you code PHP in different file I dont know for me is more clear.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are varying opinions on this. I think there are two good ways:

- Use a templating engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) that completely separates code and presentation.
- Use your second example, but when mixing PHP into HTML, *only output variables*. Do all the code logic in one block before outputting anything, or a separate file. Like so:

  ```
  <?php $content = doSomething();
     // complex calculations
  ?>
  <html>
  <body>
    <?php echo $content; ?>       
    <div id="some_div">Content</div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Most full-fledged application frameworks bring their own styles of doing this; in that case, it's usually best to follow the style provided.

Comment: I definitely agree with separating the code/html blocks if you combine both into a single file. If you know that no variables/functionality is going to change once you hit a certain point in the page, that makes it a lot easier to debug/edit stuff later. The exception I'd make to this is if you're doing iterative html output, e.g. <li> elements from arrays.

Comment: wordpress this but I think is so bad is not clean

Answer (score 12):

I think this would depend on your group's or your own decided convention. And it can and *should* vary depending on what type of file you're working in. If you follow the MVC pattern then your views should be the latter. If you're writing a class or some non-output script/code then you should use the former.

Try to keep a separation of display or formatting of output and the logic that provides the data. For instance let's say you need to make a quick page that runs a simple query and outputs some data. In this case (where there is no other existing infrastructure or framework) you could place the logic in an include or in the top or the bottom of the file. Example:

```
<?php
  # define some functions here that provide data in a raw format
?>
<html>
<body>
  <?php foreach($foo = data_function($some_parameter) as $key => $value): ?>
  <p>
    <?=$value;?>
  </p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you could place the logic and function definitions in an include file or at the bottom of the file.

Now if you're producing some sort of class that has output (*it really shouldn't*) then you would echo the HTML or return it from the method being called. Preferably return it so that it can be output whenever and however the implementer would like.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax highlighting is an important benefit of the second method, as you said. But also, if you're following good practices where logic and presentation are separated, you will naturally find that your files that contain HTML are almost entirely HTML, which then, naturally, leads to your second method again. This is the standard for MVC frameworks and the like. You'll have a bunch of files that are all PHP, doing logic, and then when that's done they'll include a presentation file which is mostly HTML with a sprinkling of PHP.

Comment: This. Most (all?) editors won't syntax highlight HTML inside a PHP string.

Comment: Some do when it's in a 'heredoc' block that is started with `<<<HTML ... HTML;` (TextMate)

Comment: That issue, the lack of highlighting inside a string, is probably my biggest problem with it, actually.

Comment: Yet the heredoc syntax kills indentation, so it's a no-no.

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

More PHP - close HTML in PHP. When you generate HTML code in PHP, when you are doing something like a class, so it is better to make it in echo.

Less PHP - close PHP in HTML. This is stuff like just putting vars into fields of HTML stuff, like forms... And such.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to separate the HTML from the PHP using template system or at least some kind of HTML skeleton like:

```
<main>
    <header/>
    <top-nav/>
    <left-col>
        <body />
    </left-col>
    <right-col />
    <footer/>
</main>
```

Each node represents a template file e.g. main.php, hrader.php and so on. Than you have to separate the PHP code from the templates as something like functions.php and fineally use your second approach for template files and keeping functions clean of "echos" and HTML.

Comment: I use this way for me and  my project is best

Answer (score 2):

If you can, use a template engine instead.

Although it is slightly easier at first to mix your HTML and PHP, separating them makes things much easier to maintain later on.

I would recommend checking out [TemplateLite](http://templatelite.sourceforge.net/) which is based on [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) but is a little more light weight.

Answer (score 1):

I've reached a conclusion that using **views** in MVC framework e.g. Laravel, Yii, CodeIgniter is the best approach even if you are not displaying the html straight away.

Inside the view do all the echoing and looping of prepared variables, don't create or call functions there, unless formatting existing data e.g. date to specific format `date('Y-m-d', strtodate(123456789)`). It should be used only for creating HTML, not processing it. That's what frameworks have controllers for.

If using plain PHP, create you own view function to pass 3 variables to - html file, array of variables, and if you want to get output as string or print it straight away for the browser. I don't find a need for it as using frameworks is pretty much a standard. <strike>(I might improve the answer in the future by creating the function to get view generated HTML)</strike> Please see added edit below as a sample.

Frameworks allow you to get the HTML of the view instead of displaying it. So if you need to generate separate tables or other elements, pass the variables to a view, and return HTML.

Different fremeworks may use various type of templating languages e.g. blade. They help formatting the data, and essentially make templates easier to work with. It's also not necessary to use them for displaying data, or if forced to use it by the framework, just do required processing before posting the variables, and just "print" it using something like `{{ yourVariable }}` or `{{ yourVariable.someProperty }}`

**Edit:** here's a plain PHP (not framework PHP) - [simple-php-view](https://github.com/cyberstunts/simple-php-view) repository as a sample view library that allows to generate HTML using variables. Could be suitable for school/university projects or such where frameworks may not be allowed.

The repository allows to generate HTML at any time by calling a function and passing required variables to it, similar to frameworks. Separately generated HTML can then be combined by another view.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.  If you are outputting a lot of HTML with attributes, you're going to get sick of escaping the quotation marks in PHP strings.  However, there is no need to use `?><p><?` instead of `echo "<p>";` either.  It's really just a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is what I usually use. And it was the default method for me too. It is just to handy to get php to work inside html rather than echo out the html code. But I had to modify the httpd.conf file as my server just commented out the php code.