# Positioning a Price Circle on an image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I think this is probably a simple thing to do but when i try to do it it messes other stuff up that I've got.

Basically I am using `php` in `codeigniter`.  I have a for loop that displays lots of product items (tours) to the user to choose and enter all the specific details related to that product.  This page is here:

http://eternalcitytours.com/en/2/Catholic-Tours-Of-Rome-Italy

On each product box there is a blue ring.

I want to substitute the yellow price circle (see example below)

http://eternalcitytours.com/en/22/Tours/Ancient-Coliseum-Roman-Forum-Rome-Tour

to be instead of this blue ring.  However every time I do it everything messes up.
The relevant bits of code are:

```css
        .feature li .thumb .date {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -25px;
      left: 110px;
      display: block;
      -moz-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
      border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 46px;
      background: #f3e4c8;
      float: left;
      font-family: mensch;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .feature li .thumb .date span {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 20px;
    }
    div .raf{
        width:16px;
        height:16px;
        border-radius:50%;
        background-color:#CE1126;
        background-clip:content-box;
        padding:8px;
        border:8px solid #00247D;
        margin-left:7px;
        margin-top:-5px;
    }
    .tour-price {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:50%;
    color:#483f34;
    line-height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ffc55f;
    align: center;
    }
```

```html
        <ul id="filter-container" class="feature cf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
                        <?php 
                    $tcount=count($tours);
                    $tcount=$tcount-1;
                    for($i=0; $i<=$tcount;$i++){
                     echo "
                        <li class=\"".$tours[$i]['location']."\">  
                                <a href=\"".$tours[$i]['nav_url']."\" class=\"thumb\">".$tours[$i]['img']."
                                <div class=\"date\"><div class=\"raf\"></div></div>
                                </a>
                                <h4 class=\"tour_title\" itemprop=\"name\">".$tours[$i]['title']."</h4>
                                <div class=\"caption\" itemprop=\"description\">".$tours[$i]['blurb']."</div>
                                <p><a href=\"".$tours[$i]['nav_url']."\" class=\"tours\" itemprop=\"url\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Read More...</button></a></p>
                        </li>
                        ";
                    }?>
                    </ul>
```

thanks

TC

Comment: If you can provide a minimal, working example using HTML/CSS, that will help us help you :)

Comment: I don't see what is a problem? Do you have example?
You already have the circle, but it has blue borders and really tiny space inside. You could remove borders, increase circles, and place prices inside. Then you would need to stylize it as you wish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code:

```
div .raf{
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#CE1126;
    background-clip:content-box;
    padding:8px;
    border:8px solid #00247D;
    margin-left:7px;
    margin-top:-5px;
}
```

to this one:

```
div .raf{
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #483f34;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffc55f;
}
```

And I suppose you want also to change the HTML, replace this:

```
<div class=\"date\"><div class=\"raf\"></div></div>
```

With this other code:

```
<div class=\"date\">
  <div class=\"raf\" itemprop=\"price\" content=\"43.00\">
     <span itemprop=\"priceCurrency\" content=\"EUR\">€</span>
  43</div>
</div>
```

**Additional recommendations:** You could improve a lot your code readability by correctly formatting your code, see thsi questions: [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318033/outputting-html-with-echo-considered-bad-practice-in-php) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148031/what-is-the-best-practice-to-use-when-using-php-and-html)

Comment: Thanks ThemesCreator.  I take on board your comments about readability too.  I will start implementing your suggestions from now on.  Very many thanks