# Preferable ways of writing PHP code in a HTML page?

Tags: php, html, function

I'm wondering if there is a standard rule or method when trying to construct a dynamic html page that consist of both html and php.

For example most of the time I code whatever pops up on my head and my php will end up looking like this:

```
<div class="front-title-blocks">
      <div class="table">
        <div class="table-row">

            <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
                if( have_rows('table_row') ):
                   while ( have_rows('table_row') ) : the_row(); ?>
                            <div class="table-cell">
                                <?php the_sub_field('single_cell'); ?>
                            </div> 
                    <?php endwhile; else :
                        // no row found
                endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile;  ?>

        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Then I noticed the same code that carried out the exact same function can be re-written like this.

```
<?php

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    function repeaterField(){
            $output='';
            if( have_rows('table-b-table') ):
                while ( have_rows('table_row') ) : the_row();
                        $output .= "<div class='table-cell'>".get_sub_field('single_cell')."</div>";
                 endwhile; else : // no row found
            endif;
            return $output;
    }

    $output = "<div class='front-title-blocks'>
                  <div class='table'>
                       <div class='table-row'>".repeaterField()."</div>
                   </div>
                </div>";
endwhile; 

echo $output;

?>
```

The difference that I noticed:

• First example has multiple opening and closing php tag that switch between html and php continuously.

• Second example tend use php all the way and can be echo out easily using a variable.

• Second example took longer time to construct and rearrange.

• For arrangement sake I feel like second one is more organize but I do notice that the first example is easier to read though.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best practice to use when using PHP and HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148031/what-is-the-best-practice-to-use-when-using-php-and-html)

Comment: In addition, you could enable short tags `<? /*some code*/ ?>`

Comment: Take a look at [Transphporm](https://github.com/Level-2/Transphporm) for a solution that completely separates the display logic from your html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option it's 'better' (or I prefered this) for various reasons:  because it's more readable, with code editors you could have syntaxis help and autocomplete and the page loads faster.

Another thing to consider is that you will be dealing with double and simple quotes in the second method that could cause errors:

`echo "<div id='a'"+$var+"'...>";`

But the 2 options are valid.

There are others questions like that: [Outputting HTML with echo considered bad practice in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318033/outputting-html-with-echo-considered-bad-practice-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

The first method is good. The second in a bad idea.

All code inside of `<?php ?>` is sent to PHP to be interpreted.This means your website is slower. So don't echo HTML tags without any reason.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out some templating engine like Twig for server side page generation.

For example Twig allows you to do this:

```
{{ var }}
```

instead of this:

```
<?php echo $var ?>
```

You can also do stuff like this:

```
<h1>Members</h1>
<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[Twig references](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation)

[gogle: php template engine](https://www.google.hr/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20templating%20engine&oq=php%20templating%20engine&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i65j69i60j69i65.3999j0j7) - for other templating engines

Answer (score 1):

There's a third choice:

```
<html>
....
<body>
....    
<?php
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();    
    if (have_rows('table-b-table')):
        while (have_rows('table_row')) : the_row();
            $var1 = get_sub_field('single_cell');
            include 'template.php';
        endwhile;
    endif;    
endwhile
?>
...
</body></html>
```

**template.php**

```
<div class='front-title-blocks'>
    <div class='table'>
        <div class='table-row'>
            <div class='table-cell'>
                <?= $var1 ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Personally I prefer this one because it minimizes HTML code within PHP tags.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, very helpful

Comment: Thousands of developers before you have stumbled across this problem and have deliberated amongst them and developed elegant, easy to use solutions for everyone to use (templating engines). You should make use of those. The learning curve is usually not very steep.

Answer (score 1):

Yess first option is good ,go with it

but we have some shortcodes tags like 
you should do settings in the php.ini file for shortcodes