# Best practice for return HTML from PHP function

Tags: php

What is best way to return HTML code from PHP function? In matter of speed and usability?

I am using variant 1, because it is most understandable but people says me that is slowest because I have code inside " " that must be parsed.

I think that this is not duplicate question from [What is the best practice to use when using PHP and HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148031/what-is-the-best-practice-to-use-when-using-php-and-html) because I talking about returning code **from function**, not just echo HTML from included file.

CASE 1

```
return "    
<div class='title'>
    <h5>        
        <a href='$permalink'>$title</a>
    </h5>
</div>
<div id='content'>
    $content
</div>
";
```

CASE 2

```
$output = '
<div class="title">
    <h5>        
        <a href="' . $permalink . '">' . $title . '</a>
    </h5>
</div>
<div id="content">' .
    $content .'
</div>
';
return $output;
```

CASE 3

```
$output  = '<div class="title">';
$output .= '<h5>';
$output .= '<a href="' . $permalink . '">' . $title . '</a>';
$output .= '</h5>';
$output .= '</div>';
$output .= '<div id="content">';
$output .= $content; 
$output .= '</div>';
return $output;
```

CASE 4

```
ob_start();
?>
<div class='title'>
    <h5>
        <a href="<?= $permalink ?>"><?= $title ?></a>
    </h5>
</div>
<div id='content'>
    <?= $content ?>
</div>";
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
```

CASE 5

```
$output = <<<HTML
<div class='title'>
    <h5>        
        <a href='$permalink'>$title</a>
    </h5>
</div>
<div id='content'>
    $content
</div>
HTML;
return $output;
```

Comment: there is a fifth option, looks more like 4 but does not use output buffer.

Comment: I think a good read might be this from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148031/what-is-the-best-practice-to-use-when-using-php-and-html/4148095#4148095  Pekka give a good answer there

Comment: I usually use option 5: HEREDOC

Comment: HEREDOC is ok but I don't use that because closing tag can not be indented.

Answer (score 1):

case 6:

Let PHP handle the data and let your templating tool handle the HTML (you can use PHP as the template tool, but something like Twig is much better)

```
<?php
function doSomething(){
    return [
        'permalink' => 'https://some.where',
        'title' => "Title",
        'Content' => "Hello World!",
    ];

}

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('template.twig.html');
$template->render(doSomething());

//content of template.twig.html
<div class='title'>
    <h5>        
        <a href='{{permalink}}'>{{title}}</a>
    </h5>
</div>
<div id='content'>
    {{content}} 
</div>
```

Twig documentation

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation